# problem in getting the text from custom list view while calling setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have made a custom list view with items and sub Items using Linked hash map. I want to set item click listener and pass the item clicked as a string on next activity through intent.

final ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_listview);

```
    final LinkedHashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.a), getString(R.string.location_a));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.b), getString(R.string.location_b));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.c), getString(R.string.location_c));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.d), getString(R.string.location_d));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.e), getString(R.string.location_e));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.f), getString(R.string.location_f));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.g), getString(R.string.location_g));
    nameAddresses.put(getString(R.string.h), getString(R.string.location_h));
    List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});


    Iterator it = nameAddresses.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
        resultsMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
        listItems.add(resultsMap);
    }

    resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    resultsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String itemClicked=nameAddresses.get(position);
            Intent intent=new Intent(seeAllHospitalsCategory.this, departments_category.class);
            intent.putExtra("Hospital Selected", itemClicked);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

get(position) is throwing a null value. The output should be the text that is contained in id text1. e.g When i click on first item, then it should pass the value in R.string.a to the resulting activity

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hashmap. Hashmap doesn't work with index, but with keys so when you try to get a specific element you use the key which is here of type String and not the index. A ListView position is an Int which causes the crash.

Comment: So, how can i achieve my desired output??

Comment: hey juste between, i have first a question and then i will give you the answer. Why did you use here an hashmap ?where the key and the value have the same value

Comment: i wanted to show a list view with items and sub items . So, i thought of using hashmap and then mapping elements in the listview accordingly.